# Accessing nested fields with Rethinkdb

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

So I have a result that looks like this

```
"data": {
  "randomkeyllasdkjflk": {
     "name": "John Doe"
  },
  "anotherrandomkeyadf": {
     "name": "Mona Lee"
  }
}
```

and I want to access the name.

This is what I tried:

```
r.table('users').filter(function (doc) {

      return doc('data').coerceTo('array').map(function(ref) {
        return ref('name')
      }).contains("John")

    });
```

But will produce an error that says:

> e: Cannot perform bracket on a non-object non-sequence
>   `"randomkeyllasdkjflk"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
r.table('users').filter(function (doc) {

  return doc('data').keys().map(function(ref) {
    return doc('data')(ref)('name')
  }).contains("John")

});
```